# Почему Python выдаёт ошибку

Tags: python, python-3.x

Когда пользователь вводит число 0, программа должна завершиться. Помогите найти и исправить ошибку.

```
# a и b
a = int(input("Введите первое число:"))
b = int(input("Введите второе число:"))

# выход из программы
if a == 0:
    break

# вывести сумму чисел
print(a + b)
```

Python3 выдаёт ошибку

> SyntaxError: 'break' outside loop

Спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`break` используется для выхода из цикла, для завершения программы нужно использовать `exit(0)`